# Which component/view I should use to show single image preview in Android?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

Situation:

I have a listview with images. Listview is in Activity. On every image click I want to download full resolution image and show it in separate view. Which android app component/view is the best to use as my "separate view" from performance and best android app design practices point of view? For sure I don't want to use another Activity for just single image preview. I am thinking to use a Fragment but maybe Android have another component/view (eg. something similar like gallery view or etc.) which I don't know to achieve such a goal?

Comment: go for custom dialog  with `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use default android gallery instead of creating an activity or even a fragment. Add this code to your ImageView onClick in the listview

```
// Write the path of your image then view it in the default gallery
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                            + "your image location, name and extension";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)),"image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can I pass image to gallery not from file but from remote url?

Comment: No unfortunately, you have to save the image to your device then you can open it.